# Angular Lib dependencies

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-library

I'm trying to build an angular library to be used in a few different apps. When I install `@angular/material`, I can compile the library but keep getting an error such as the one below when I try use the library in an app. What am I missing?

```bash
./src/app/app.module.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i8.MatInputModule to symbol
    at .../Documents/git/dialogeditor/ngx-sample-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/loader.js:81:18
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Error: node_modules/dialog/lib/dialog.module.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/material/input' or its corresponding type declarations.

9 import * as i8 from "@angular/material/input";
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Please show how you’ve imported MatInputModule to the exported NgModule

Comment: Standard way for a normal ng project

`import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';`

then

`imports: [..., MatInputModule],`